# Unable to use L.Routing.control of leaflet maps

Tags: routes, maps, leaflet, controls

I am trying to use the sample from here: http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/pu39s9wn/

In my local I have the code as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <button class="route-btn" onclick="ResetRoute()">Reset Button</button>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>

    <script>
        var map = new L.Map('map').setView([34.07, -118.2], 11);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        var route = L.Routing.control({
            plan: L.Routing.plan([
                L.latLng(34.06, -118.25),
                L.latLng(34.02, -118.5)
            ], {
                createMarker: function(i, wp) {
                    return L.marker(wp.latLng, {
                        draggable: true,
                        icon: new L.Icon.Label.Default({ labelText: String.fromCharCode(65 + i) })
                    });
                },
                routeWhileDragging: true
            }),
            fitSelectedRoutes: false,
            routeWhileDragging: true,
            routeDragTimeout: 250,
            showAlternatives: true
        }).addTo(map);


        ResetRoute = function () {
            route.setWaypoints([L.latLng(map.getCenter()), L.latLng(map.getCenter())]);
        }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am getting an error in the developers console:

```
TypeError: L.Routing is undefined
dire.html:22:9
ReferenceError: ResetRoute is not defined
```

And the route is not shown as stuck for a long time, please point out what is  wrong here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/hW5osTLfwZ4bD4cGeNjT?p=preview (using leaflet-routing-machine v3.0.3). Note however that your page does not include the script for `L.Icon.Label` (I commented out the corresponding use on your code)

Comment: prefect  my reference to leaflet-routing-machine.js was incorrect